# Is the degree of a function related to the degree of its derivative on a Riemann surface?

Tags: riemann-surfaces, holomorphic-functions

$\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}, z \to z^n$ is of degree n and its derivative of degree $n-1$. But in another chart, the function is $u \to \frac{1}{u^n}$ and its derivative is $\frac{-n}{u^{n+1}}$, of degree n+1.

What am I getting wrong here? Note: I use "degree" as in "degree of the covering of $X \to f(X)$"

Comment: In fact the degree of $\dfrac{1}{u^n}$ is $-n$ not $n$.

Comment: What is "its derivative" in terms of a Riemann surface? It depends on your coordinate. The coordinate free operation is to go from $f$ (a function) to $\mathrm{d}f$ (a $1$-form). This will increase the total order of poles by one. In the coordinate $z$ you have a pole at $z=\infty$ and for $u$ you have one at $u=0$, in both cases of order $n$ for the function and $n+1$ for the $1$-form.